# Showing the complex function is differentiable in a set of points

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I´ve to show if the function:

$f(x+iy)=2x^2+4iy$

Is differentiable at some points in $\mathbb{C}$.

Checking the Cuchy Riemann equations, the function can only be differentiable at points of the form

$z=1+iy$

Then, taking the limit

$\lim_{h_1,h_2\to0}\frac{f(1+iy+h_1+ih_2)-f(1+iy)}{h_1+ih_2}=\lim_{h_1,h_2\to0}\frac{2h_1^2}{h_1+ih_2}+4=4$

Is this enough to show that the function $f$ is only differentiable at points of the form $z=1+iy$ ?

Comment: $\frac{f(1+iy+h_1+ih_2)-f(1+iy)}{h_1+ih_2} \ne \frac{h_1^2}{h_1+ih_2}+4$. (And even if it were, you would be in error in not having the "$\lim$" present in the RH side. Remember: "=" means that the things on either side are *exactly* the same. It does not mean "kinda related to each other".)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it

Comment: You need to (1) actually show that the Cauchy-Riemann conditions fail to hold anywhere else and (2) show that $\lim_{h_1,h_2\to0}\frac{2h_1^2}{h_1+ih_2} =0$ As this is a $0/0$ form, it isn't automatic. However, I don't think it was necessary to go all the way back to the definition for this. The fact that the partials of $\Re(f)$ and $\Im(f)$ exist everywhere, and the CR conditions are satisfied on $z = 1 + iy$ is sufficient.